# Xcode drag and drop ViewController from one project to another

Tags: xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

It happens that the IBOutlets in the new project are connecting to the storyboard of the original project? How to avoid? Or how to disconnect from the ViewController code?

[image]

Here you can see MainStoryboard_iphone is storyboard in original project, Main_iPhone_storyboard is storyboard in the new project.

Thanks.

Comment: So you have 2 storyboards with the same outlets in 1 project?

Comment: @SergiusGee, No, I have two storyboards from two projects. I want just to copy classes build from one project to another. I don't want outlets to be carried from one project to another. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a simple hack if you don't have a lot of classes - create new files for every header file where you declare your `IBOutlets` and copy over the code - it might as well solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the only way. Sadly, I have a lot of classes to copy.